# Solrj Client Vs Plain HTTP Calls

Tags: performance, concurrency, solr, solrj

I have tried to communicate with Solr through `Solrj` client and also through `plain HTTP` calls. Both are working fine.

But,

- Which among these options would be a better bid?
- Which can be considered as a standard Industrial practice?
- Which will support high concurrency (for searching Index  and updating Index)?
- Which will provide better performance (in terms of response time and memory space consumption)?

Any information on this comparison is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge Solrj is the most used java client library for Solr. I saw some discussions on performance of Solrj before (http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Query-Delete-performance-difference-between-straight-HTTP-and-SolrJ-td3438321.html and [SolrJ used to control Solr/Luce vs. Straight Rest Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261219/solrj-used-to-control-solr-luce-vs-straight-rest-calls)) but at the end it seems that Solrj does perform well (in my system I still have no complaints)... I do think the performance issues are more related with "how you index" and manipulate your solr documents, probably your should think on those terms, since at the end you will need to develop yourself the HTTP calls (that Solrj handles for you and has some extra functionality to help you - see the second reference I gave, it is question similar to yours).

Comment: I do agree with the fact that performance highly depends on the way we index and manipulate documents.. I was just curious about the difference in concurrency and performance when we take the HTTP route and Solrj route.. Thanks a lot for your effort!